# python date range list elements

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, range, date-range

I want to do range(start,end). I have days, ex

```
    start date -  end date
    -----------------------
    2015-05-17 - 2015-05-25
    2015-06-10 - 2015-06-20
    -----------------------

    startdate = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 17), datetime.date(2015, 6, 10)]
    enddate = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), datetime.date(2015, 6, 20)]

i need range startdate and enddate 

need_days = startdate[i] - enddate[i]
1. datetime.date(2015, 5, 25) - datetime.date(2015, 5, 17)
2. atetime.date(2015, 6, 20), datetime.date(2015, 6, 10)

after i want range separate
result
------------
2015-05-17
2015-05-18
2015-05-19
2015-05-20
2015-05-21
2015-05-22
2015-05-23
2015-05-24
2015-05-25

result
----------
2015-06-10
2015-06-11
2015-06-12
2015-06-13
2015-06-14
2015-06-15
2015-06-16
2015-06-17
2015-06-18
2015-06-19
2015-06-20
```

How can I achieve this? Help me please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use range with [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects),getting the numbers of days with `(end-start).days+1)`.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
start,end = datetime(2015, 5, 17), datetime(2015, 5, 25)
dates = [start + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((end-start).days+1)]
for dte in dates:
    print(dte.date())

2015-05-17
2015-05-18
2015-05-19
2015-05-20
2015-05-21
2015-05-22
2015-05-23
2015-05-24
2015-05-25
```

The logic is exactly the same for your second range.

```
start,end = datetime(2015, 6, 10), datetime(2015, 6, 20)
dates = [start + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((end-start).days+1)]
for dte in dates:
    print(dte.date())

2015-06-10
2015-06-11
2015-06-12
2015-06-13
2015-06-14
2015-06-15
2015-06-16
2015-06-17
2015-06-18
2015-06-19
2015-06-20
```

If you have to use the two lists use zip:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
start_dates = [date(2015, 5, 17), date(2015, 6, 10)]
end_dates = [date(2015, 5, 25), date(2015, 6, 20)]
dates = [start + timedelta(days=i) for start, end in zip(start_dates,end_dates) for i in range((end-start).days+1) ]
for dte in dates:
    print(dte)
```

Output:

```
2015-05-17
2015-05-18
2015-05-19
2015-05-20
2015-05-21
2015-05-22
2015-05-23
2015-05-24
2015-05-25
2015-06-10
2015-06-11
2015-06-12
2015-06-13
2015-06-14
2015-06-15
2015-06-16
2015-06-17
2015-06-18
2015-06-19
2015-06-20
```

Comment: hello bro, yes i agree, it is true but i need the exapmle above  startdate = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 17), datetime.date(2015, 6, 10)]
    enddate = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), datetime.date(2015, 6, 20)]

Comment: i have start date(17,10) and end date(25,20) after i need range

Comment: u to misunderstand, it works but i need other method

Comment: I have 2 or more items in start date, startdate = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 17), datetime.date(2015, 6, 10)]

Comment: Yes but the locic is exactly the same just do what i have in my answer

Comment: how to do? can u show me exaple, i tried so, abc = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 17), datetime.date(2015, 5, 21)]
 cba = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 20), datetime.date(2015, 5, 25)] start,end = abc,cba dates = [start+td(days=i) for i in range((end-start).days+1)]
i get typeerror TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: @PyDroid. I added the code,it is literally exactly the same bar changing the start and end date

Comment: thanks bro but u dont understand, i want all together as i have shown above, together a starting days and together a ending days 
startdate = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 17), datetime.date(2015, 6, 10)]
    enddate = [datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), datetime.date(2015, 6, 20)]

Comment: @PyDroid, I edited the answer, if that is not it I am afraid I have no idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78346/discussion-between-pydroid-and-padraic-cunningham).